# Error when right click vuejs app

Tags: vue.js, compiler-errors, vuex

When I right-click m vuejs and my vuex app, I got the error after each click:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: o is not defined
>       at HTMLDocument.document.addEventListener.t (:1:784)

in VM file. I research in google bt I cannot find how can I fix that error.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled the extension and it seems to have taken care of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too, disable your [vue Devtools] plugin will help

Comment: Thanks, I got it =))

Comment: Same problem here but disabling the devtools shouldn't be the answer!

Comment: Yeah - it shouldn't. But it *is* the answer. That's a bug in the plugin. Until they fix it, disabling is the only way around it.